What is the origin story of panel planes?
What is the general history or origin story of panel planes?
I’ve tried looking it up in books like The Handplane Book by Garrett Hack, Handplane Essentials, Revised & Expanded by Christopher Schwartz, as well as others from UK authors like Jim Kingshott and David Charleston but haven’t came upon a clear “this type of plane did not exist yet but woodworkers needed it, so it became a thing” kind of explanation.
I also tried looking around to see if Moxon mentions this type of plane or if a translation of Roubo’s works talk about it but haven’t found mention.
I’ve found information about how Norris and Spiers were known early makers of this type of infill plane, but I’m curious why there came about a jointer/smoother plane for panels in particular given frame and panel construction had been around for a long time already and the name “panel plane” does not seem to appear in documents prior to Spiers’ Victorian-era marketing.
(To clarify, I’m curious about panel planes and not panel-raising planes.)

Welcome back to Woodworking! But as an experienced SEer you know that prior research is required by the model? As there's no sign of any research here this is demanding a downvote for "This question does not show any research effort". Plus, one query per Q.

Thanks! I didn’t know about the prior research bit but I’ll add it now and narrow the question.

I also noticed that Joel from Tools For Working Wood’s blog mentions “[in] ‘The Wooden Plane,’ John Whelan suggests that the strike-block plane might have been an ancestor of the English panel plane” which might be a clue?

Interestingly a page on Joel's site seems to pretty much answer exactly what you're now asking, even though it's not exclusively about panel planes (will be the first link in my Answer). This was literally the first thing I found doing a test search yesterday, and I just found a further page again from Joel using a different search term. If it helps for the future, when looking for stuff like this it's sometimes useful to try searching both with and without quotes, although generally to hone in on a specific topic properly you do need to use quotes, so e.g. origin of "British panel plane"


haven’t came upon a clear “this type of plane did not exist yet but woodworkers needed it, so it became a thing” kind of explanation

The following page on Joel Moskowitz's site Tools for Working Wood appears to give just the explanation you're looking for, National Priorities in Early Metal Planemaking. An excerpt:
The metal plane showed up in England in the late 1700's as a great plane for marquetry -- with the form we now now as a "mitre plane". Better-heeled woodworkers quickly discovered that these metal planes were ... not only great for marquetry, but also for planing difficult woods. The metal body was stable, didn't wear, and worked consistently well. The only issue was that mitre planes were uncomfortable to use, so throughout the early 19th century we see mitre planes with handles cobbled up into them. This trend culminated in the form of the panel plane above, which is actually constructed like a mitre plane but has a regular handle like a wooden panel plane.
This ties in with other things I've read over the years about the origin of such planes, the where and why. The specific use-cases usually mentioned — highly figured woods, marquetry — were of course not new to European woodworking, what had changed was the demand for both. With urbanisation and a rise in affluence increasing demand, it drove a need to produce this kind of work more efficiently. And going hand-in-hand with this, it saw the rise of a class of woodworker who could afford them1.
Additional information, also from Joel, is on this tantalisingly titled page, Robert Towell - Inventor of the Infill Panel Plane. The relevant paragraph:
His first metal planes were miter planes and were much like everyone else's miter planes. Then Towell started making rebate planes. I don't know if he was the inventor of that design, but sometime probably in the 1830s - 1840s, Towell realized that most people were using their miter planes like regular bench planes. Ergonomically miter planes sucked, as there was just no place to properly grab a miter plane and put power behind it. Towell made some of the first metal panel planes, including the one in these photos. The actual shape of his panel plane wasn't new - it existed in wood for over a century previously - but making it out of metal was an innovation.
I think many modern woodworkers will grok this at least on a gut level. While there were then, and still are, various ways to skin any particular cat when you have a tool that works well you do tend to try to find as many jobs as possible for it! Especially the case if you're a tool minimalist, a he who dies with the fewest tools wins kind of person :-)

1 In contrast to the majority of woodworking craftsmen for the preceding 100-150 years. Even by a generation or two previous to this, individual craftsmen were still not generally well-heeled..... many might even be considered impoverished — working hand-to-mouth or close to it — despite the quality of the work they could produce, and fast.

This helps, thanks! I ended up poring through Joel’s writings on the subject but I’m still coming up empty on why “panel planes” became a new classification of plane. It looks like wood smoothers had metal bodied evolutions, and the same for wood to metal try/jointers, and eventually jacks. However, what’s up with “panel plane”? Why did the craft need a new classification?
